# JAR isn't compatible when downloaded

Tags: java, windows, jar, download

I created a JAR for a GUI update system that downloads an executable file inside of itself and executes it. This works perfectly for me whenever I run the original copy. However, when downloaded from the Internet, the GUI breaks. The header font reverts to the original font, and the download button activates the scheduled dialog box but therein does nothing with downloading the file. Remember that *my* original copy of `setup.jar` works, but the downloaded version does nothing.

The JAR can be found [here](http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/), but specifically for the direct download you may find it [here](http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/setup.jar).

Here are the contents of my JAVA file & a picture of the JAR's hierarchy:

```
public class UpdateMechanism extends JFrame
                                implements ActionListener {
    protected static JButton aroundTheLake; 
    protected static JFrame frame;

    private static JButton aroundTheRiver() {
        aroundTheLake = new JButton("DOWNLOAD & INSTALL!");
        aroundTheLake.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        aroundTheLake.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING); //aka LEFT, for left-to-right locales
        aroundTheLake.addActionListener(new UpdateMechanism());
        aroundTheLake.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        aroundTheLake.setActionCommand("aroundthelake");
        return aroundTheLake;
    }

    private static String readURL(String targetURL) {
        String returnish = "";
        try {
            URL tempURL = new URL(targetURL); 
            Scanner s = new Scanner(tempURL.openStream()); 
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                returnish = returnish+s.nextLine(); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e); 
        }
        return returnish;
    }

    private static String readFile(String targetFile) { 
        String returnString = "";
        try {
            File tempFile = new File(targetFile);
            Scanner s = new Scanner(tempFile);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                returnString = returnString + s.nextLine(); 
            }
        } catch(IOException e) { 
            // !
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("aroundthelake".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                            "Please wait, this may take a while depending on your connection...");
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    URL url; 
                    URLConnection con;  
                    DataInputStream dis;  
                    FileOutputStream fos; 
                    byte[] fileData;  
                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net/project/theneverhood/setup.exe");
                        con = url.openConnection(); 
                        dis = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
                        fileData = new byte[con.getContentLength()]; 
                        for (int x = 0; x < fileData.length; x++) { 
                            fileData[x] = dis.readByte();
                        }
                        dis.close(); 
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("executable/setup.exe"));  
                        fos.write(fileData);
                        fos.close(); 
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("executable/setup.exe", null, new File("executable/"));
                    }
                    catch(MalformedURLException m) {
                        System.out.println(m);
                    }
                    catch(IOException io) {
                        System.out.println(io);
                    }
                }   
            }.start();
        } else {
            // man
        }
    }

    private static void showGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("The Neverhood Restoration Project");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0xA64343));

        File fileCheck = new File("C:/Program Files (x86)");
        String returnString = null;
        String rootDirectory = null;
        if (fileCheck.exists()) {
            rootDirectory = "C:/Program Files (x86)/DreamWorks Interactive"; 
            String checkFile = rootDirectory+"/Neverhood/version.txt"; 
            File tempFile = new File(checkFile);
            if (tempFile.exists()) {
                returnString = readFile(checkFile);
            } else {
                returnString = "It appears you do not have the Neverhood Restoration Project installed, or you are using an earlier version."; 
            }
        } else {
            rootDirectory = "C:/Program Files/DreamWorks Interactive";
            String checkFile = rootDirectory+"/Neverhood/version.txt"; 
            File tempFile = new File(checkFile);
            if (tempFile.exists()) {
                returnString = readFile(checkFile);
            } else {
                returnString = "It appears you do not have the Neverhood Restoration Project installed, or you are using an earlier version.";
            }
        }
        if (returnString.equals(readURL("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/version.txt"))) {
            returnString = "You are updated to the recent version!"; 
        } else { 
            returnString = "It appears you're not updated.";
        }

        JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("The Neverhood Restoration Project");
        headerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        JPanel heapPanel = new JPanel();
        heapPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(heapPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        heapPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, heapPanel.getPreferredSize().height));
        JTextArea heapLabel = new JTextArea(50, 50);        
        heapLabel.setLineWrap(true);
        heapLabel.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        heapLabel.setEditable(false);
        heapLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 10, 20));
        heapLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        heapLabel.append("Current version: "+readURL("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/prettyversion.txt")+".\nInstalled version: "+readFile(rootDirectory+"/Neverhood/prettyversion.txt")+".\n"+returnString+"\n" + 
            "You can read the full version of the document to the left at http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net."
            + "\nHaven't installed yet? Below is the download button. Just click to save setup.exe in and enjoy!");
        heapPanel.add(heapLabel);
        if (returnString == "It appears you're not updated.") { 
            heapPanel.add(aroundTheRiver());
        }

        try {
            Font sFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("DUGFB___.TTF"));
            sFont = sFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 48);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(sFont);
            headerLabel.setFont(sFont);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        BufferedImage icoImage = null;
        try {
            icoImage = ImageIO.read(
                frame.getClass().getResource("/nhood.bmp"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        frame.setIconImage(icoImage);

        JEditorPane updateLog = new JEditorPane();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(updateLog);
        updateLog.setEditable(false);

        try {
            updateLog.setPage("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            updateLog.setContentType("text/html");
            updateLog.setText("<html>The application could not load the webpage.</html>");
        }

        frame.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.add(heapPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: The poorly illustrated arrow points to "executable," not META-INF.]

This picture is from when it is downloaded from the provided link.
[image: The JAR when downloaded from the Internet.]

Comment: The code is buggy at several places. You should probably test each method individually and then move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many small bugs in the code:

```
    new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                URL url; 
                URLConnection con;  
                DataInputStream dis;  
                FileOutputStream fos; 
                byte[] fileData;  
                try {
                    url = new URL("http://hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net/project/theneverhood/setup.exe");
                    con = url.openConnection(); 
                    dis = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
                    fileData = new byte[con.getContentLength()]; 
                    for (int x = 0; x < fileData.length; x++) { 
                        fileData[x] = dis.readByte();
                    }
                    dis.close(); 
                    File f = new File("executable");
                    if(!f.isDirectory())
                        f.mkdir();
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("executable/setup.exe"));  
                    fos.write(fileData);
                    fos.close(); 

                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("executable/setup.exe", null, new File("executable/"));
                }
                catch(MalformedURLException m) {
                    System.out.println(m);
                }
                catch(IOException io) {
                    System.out.println(io);
                }
            }   
        }.start();
```

Plus, what I will suggest is to use a ProcessBuilder instead of `Runtime`.
Example:

```
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("cmd");
    command.add("/C");
    File dcr = new File("executable/setup.exe");
    dcr.setExecutable(true, false);
    command.add(dcr.getAbsolutePath());
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    final Process process = builder.start();
    try {
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WhatEver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    InputStream is = process.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Logger.getLogger(Thumbnail.class.getName()).severe(line);
    }
```

Secondly, Font is not right, because it throws an exception at

`Font sFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("DUGFB___.TTF"));` And hence the font is not as desired.

Also change `returnString == "It appears you're not updated."` to `returnString.equals("It appears you're not updated.")`